# How to change the size of the text

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, text-size

How to change the text and image size of my `ListTile`.

```
child: ListTile(
                      title: Center(
                          child: Text(infoBank[PicNumber].title),
                      ),
                       textColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

```
child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 2,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    height: 350,
                    width: 350,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: infoBank[PicNumber].image,

                    ),
                  ),
```

[image: How my app is no]

Comment: use `fit:BoxFit.cover` for image and `TextStyle` for text and there are some limitation on constrains on `ListTile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Text use, Text style and u can find Font size with FontWeight and other Properties, To increase the size of an image put it inside Container with a certain height and width.

Answer (score 1):

To change text size use `style` property

```dart
Text(
    infoBank[PicNumber].title, 
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: font_size_value),
),
```

To change image size wrap it with `Container` and use `height` and `width` properties

```dart
Container(
    height: height_value,
    width: width_value,
    child: infoBank[PicNumber].image,
),
```